# Change the column name of editable field for django model admin

Tags: python, django

I have models like this, but I want to change the column name of `keyword`

```
class BlackListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['keyword','match','target']
    list_editable = ['keyword']
```

So, I made custom function `_keyword` and then.

```
class BlackListAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['_keyword','match','target']
    #list_editable = ['keyword']
    def _keyword(self,obj):
       return obj
    _keyword.short_description = 'This is the Column Name'
```

OK, it works, column name is changed, but there is one problem.

`list_editable` shows error.

How can I change the column title and keep `list_editable`??

Comment: Why not using [versbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) on model?

Comment: You solve my problem in a perfect way.....thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [versbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) on your model difinition like below example:

```py
class BlackList(models.Model):
    ...
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="_keyword")
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you your comment and answer helps me very much.